# Rearrange dictionary so that value is the next key

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
{1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 5, 4: 1, 5: 2}
```

I would like to rearrange it so that the value of the current pair is the key of the next pair, like this:

```
{1: 3, 3: 5, 5: 2, 2: 4, 4: 1}
```

How can I approach this?

Comment: As far as I remember, a python dict is not specified to be ordered so there is no ordering in the key-value pairs. The order you see when printing the dictionary is arbitrary. Edit: this seems to be the case [now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6) :) I think you would have to create a new dictionary and insert the keys in the right order from the start as I don't think they are re-orderable.

Comment: Take a look at OrderedDict structure type: https://pymotw.com/3/collections/ordereddict.html

Comment: Check [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: Actually, as of Python 3.6, [dictionaries are ordered by insertion order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using the following code - dictionaries as of [Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) (Python 3.6 for CPython) are ordered by insertion, so we start with the first key from `d`, and iterate through, updating the next key to check using the value from the last key, until the length of our new dictionary is the same as our old dictionary.

**Code:**

```
d = {1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 5, 4: 1, 5: 2}

curr = list(d.keys())[0]

d_new = {}

while len(d) > len(d_new):
    d_new[curr] = curr = d[curr]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> d_new
{1: 3, 3: 5, 5: 2, 2: 4, 4: 1}
```

**Below Python 3.7, you can use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):**

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 5, 4: 1, 5: 2}

curr = 1

d_new = OrderedDict()

while len(d) > len(d_new):
    d_new[curr] = curr = d[curr]
```

Per the comments below, if the key/values contain a loop, we want to move to the next key-value pair. This can be achieved as follows:

**Code:**

```
d = {1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2}

curr = list(d.keys())[0]

d_new = {}

while len(d) > len(d_new):
    if curr not in d_new:
        d_new[curr] = curr = d[curr]
    else:
        curr = next(x for x in d.keys() if x not in d_new)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> d_new
{1: 3, 3: 1, 2: 4, 4: 1, 5: 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using accumulate from itertools:

```
d = {1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 5, 4: 1, 5: 2}

from itertools import accumulate
od = {k:d[k] for k in accumulate(d,lambda k,_:d[k]) }

#od : {1: 3, 3: 5, 5: 2, 2: 4, 4: 1}
```

Comment: `{k:d[k] for k in accumulate(d,d.get)}` also works.